# My bees have a mite infestation but not sure whether they are Varroa Mites

Tags: animal-behaviour, bugs, bees, garden

There is a slight infestation of a type of mites (I'm not sure whether they are Varroa Mites). I would like to seek some expert opinion regarding this kind of mites that take over in the bee colony. They seem harmless but some of the weak bees are dying due to their effects. If anybody is aware of these kinds of pests/mites, a comment would be highly valuable.

I have posted the YouTube- video in the following link.

[Macro Footage of Bee Mites](https://youtu.be/hoTI1RZ8-jg)

Still photo
[image]

Comment: Is the youtube video a video of your bees, or someone else's?

Comment: It is mine I shot it using a macro lens